# While starting Airflow Webserver : ImportError: cannot import name EscapeFormatter

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

Were getting this error post installation of Airflow, while starting webserver.
Below is the error,

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
.format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 27, in 
args.func(args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 678, in webserver
app = cached_app(conf)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 161, in cached_app
app = create_app(config)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 59, in create_app
from airflow.www import views
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 49, in 
from jinja2.sandbox import ImmutableSandboxedEnvironment
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/sandbox.py", line 25, in 
**from markupsafe import EscapeFormatter
ImportError: cannot import name EscapeFormatter**
```

Comment: We were working on this issue, from last one day. Only purpose to post question along with workaround is, it will help someone else in the community who might land up with the same problem. Please comment if have better solution on this.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: 
As it seems to be python package related issue, tried to check if the package markupsafe exists at path `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/`

It does exists, so tried to import it as `from markupsafe import EscapeFormatter in python shell`, but there also it gives same error. May be files are corrupt.

Re-installing package and importing again, helped me.

```
sudo pip uninstall markupsafe
sudo pip install markupsafe
```

After this, from markupsafe import EscapeFormatter worked well in python shell.

Now start Airflow webserver and it works fine : `airflow webserver -p 8080`

Answer (score 1):

Three years ago, python2.7 ...
Now, another `markupsafe` error is haunting python3.9:

> from markupsafe import soft_unicode
> ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

The reason is that the default version of `markupsafe` is `markupSafe-2.1.0` which does not involve the required component `soft_unicode`.

It could be that `EscapeFormatter` was (is) not involved by `markupsafe` at that time's version.

My Solution is to uninstall the existed 'markupsafe', then install the correct version.  If you install directly, pip will return an error like

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Cannot move the non-empty directory  '/...path of the directory.../'

In my workstation, I walked through the following two steps:

1. Uninstall the existed markupsafe-2.1.0: `sudo pip uninstall markupsafe`
2. Install markupsafe-2.0.1: `pip install markupsafe==2.0.1`